# How to add a new item to this array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, c#-4.0, .net-4.5

I have a class -

```
public class PropertyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the array which is part of my request model

```
public PropertyModel[] Properties { get; set; }
```

This array is populated by the user and sometimes it can be empty too.

Irrespective of whether it is populated or not - I want to add a Name/Value pair - `["Origin", "WEB"]`  always to this array.

How do I do this array addition? Should I be converting this to a `List` first, add and then convert it back to an array?

Comment: `Array.Resize` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051

Comment: SO you want to add items at some later points, and you are not aware about the length of the collection initially, then why are you stick on arrays? why not `List<PropertyModel>`

Answer (score 2):

For this time you should use `List<PropertyModel>` instead for the `PropertyModel[]`. since you were not aware of the final size of the collection, the user may add new items to the collection at some later points. SO I would suggest you to define the property like this:

```
private List<PropertyModel> _Properties = new List<PropertyModel>();
public List<PropertyModel> MyProperty
{
   get { return _Properties; }
   set { myVar = _Properties; }
}
```

Please remember the following points when you faced the same confusion:

- If you are aware about the final size of the collection the you can
  use T[] or List.
- If you are not aware about the final
  size(collection size varies), the use List.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this but if you want to only add one item, then, try this code.

```
 PropertyModel[] arr = {};
 var toAdd = new PropertyModel() { Name = "Origin", Value = "WEB" };
 arr = arr.Concat(new PropertyModel[] { toAdd }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **List** instead of using **PropertyModel[]** array. With **List**  You can make your code easier like this:

```
public static List<PropertyModel> GetAll()
{
    List<PropertyModel> myList= new List<PropertyModel>();
    myList.Add(new PropertyModel(){Name = "Anna", Value = "500$"});
    myList.Add(new PropertyModel(){Name = "Michellen", Value = "520$"});

    return myList;
}
```

You can use .ToArray() method of List for

```
public PropertyModel[] Properties { get; set; }
```

Here is the code

```
//to use the function
    public static void Main()
    {
       Properties = GetAll().ToArray();

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using ArrayList : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx

It is easier to add and work with objects and whenever you need an array, you can call the .ToArray() method.

Comment: Do not use `ArrayList`. It is deprecated for like 10+ years by now. Use generic `List<T>`